# i have to make a project for my Programming course.This is my code

Tags: java, joptionpane, degrees

```
public class Project1{

    public static void main(String[] args)

    int noOfPhotocopy;
    float totalprice;

    String customer's_name;
    customer's_name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter customer's name: ");

    String type;
    type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose type of photocopy: G/C");

    if (type==G){
    noOfPhotocopy = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter no of photocopy: ");

    if (noOfPhotocopy<10){
    totalprice = noOfPhotocopy * 0.10;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total price is RM" +totalprice);
    } else if(noOfPhotocopy>=10) {
    totalprice = noOfPhotocopy * 0.05;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total price is RM" +totalprice);
    }

    else if (type==C){
    noOfPhotocopy = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter no of photocopy: ");

    if (noOfPhotocopy<10){
    totalprice = noOfPhotocopy * 0.20;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total price is RM" +totalprice);
    } else if(noOfPhotocopy>=10) {
    totalprice = noOfPhotocopy * 0.10;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total price is RM" +totalprice);
    }
 }
```

i have to make a project for my Programming course and my project is to help people to calculate total price of photocopying with different type of photocopy.

Comment: am I missing something with your question or is it there is nothing mentioned about the error or what's wrong with your code?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: but it dont work for C.

Comment: @Suhaila Salim, I modify it, now work with G and C too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are error, I fixed them.
like

```
if (type==G){// to compare use type.equals("G")
```

and

```
 String customer = "s_name";// not String customer"s_name;
```

and

```
 float totalprice; // to double totaleprice
```

Try this solution it's OK

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

public class Project1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int noOfPhotocopy;
    double totalprice;

    String customer = "s_name";
    customer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter customer's name: ");

    String type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose type of photocopy: G/C").toUpperCase();

    if (type.equals("G")) {
        noOfPhotocopy = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Enter no of photocopy: "));

        if (noOfPhotocopy < 10) {
            totalprice = noOfPhotocopy * 0.10;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total price is RM"
                    + totalprice);
        } else if (noOfPhotocopy >= 10) {
            totalprice = noOfPhotocopy * 0.05;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total price is RM"
                    + totalprice);
        }
    }
        else if (type.equals("C")) {
            noOfPhotocopy = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Enter no of photocopy: "));

            if (noOfPhotocopy < 10) {
                totalprice = noOfPhotocopy * 0.20;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total price is RM"
                        + totalprice);
            } else if (noOfPhotocopy >= 10) {
                totalprice = noOfPhotocopy * 0.10;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total price is RM"
                        + totalprice);
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. i've tried it. it only works for G but not working for C. how to fix it?